# masm assembly how to access structure variable

Tags: assembly, struct, masm

DPT is a structure defined like this:

```
DPT STRUC
rSrtHdUnld DB 1; Bits 0-3: SRT step rate time, bits 4-7: head unload time.
rDmaHdLd   DB 1; Bit  0: 1=use DMA, bits 2-7: head load time.
bMotorOff  DB 1; 55-ms increments before turning disk motor off.
bSectSize  DB 1; Sector size (0=128, 1=256, 2=512, 3=1024).
bLastTrack DB 1; EOT (last sector on a track).
bGapLen    DB 1; Gap length for read/write operations.
bDTL       DB 1; DTL (Data Transfer Length) max transfer when length not set.
bGapFmt    DB 1; Gap length for format operation.
bFillChar  DB 1; Fill character for format (normally 0f6H).
bHdSettle  DB 1; Head-settle time (in milliseconds).
bMotorOn   DB 1; Motor-startup time (in 1/8th-second intervals)
DPT ENDS ; Size=11.
```

while assembling in MASM I used following syntax:

```
MOVB [DI-SIZEOF DPT]+[DPT.bHdSettle],15
```

MASM is showing following error:

```
syntax error : [
```

Comment: If this is masm, normally the syntax would be something like `mov [di-sizeof dpt].dpt.bHdSettle, 15`. Why is di pointing to the end of the structure, not the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what `movb` is supposed to be, but I assume it's a typo and you really meant `mov`.

You can either write the instruction like this:

```
mov (DPT PTR [DI-SIZEOF DPT]).bHdSettle,15
```

Or if you're inside a `PROC` where you want to do multiple structure accesses through `di` you can tell the assembler to temporarily assume that `di` points to a `DPT`:

```
ASSUME di:PTR DPT
mov [di-SIZEOF DPT].bHdSettle,15
.....
ASSUME di:NOTHING
```